# What distro for my PowerBook G4?

Tags: apt, distribution-choice, powerpc

I've got an old PowerBook G4 with a 1333 MHz CPU and 1.25 GB RAM.

What are some good distro to use? I tried Yellow Dog and Fedora (which didn't work), but I would prefer something more Debian-like, with apt and all that.

Comment: Related: [Need Advice: What Linux distro should I install on an old PowerPC Mac](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8234/15630).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [PowerPC port](http://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/) of Debian, which [should work](http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/powerbook) (note: slightly old tutorial) on a PowerBook G4.

Comment: +1 I have successfully installed this port on an old PowerBook G4 17" and it works very well. The process is also well documented on their website.

Comment: It seems that it is no longer available since Debian 9.

Answer (score 2):

Free BSD 9 is one of the best Unix systems I have seen for PPC hardware, if you do not mind the subtle differences from Linux. It is also up to date. BSD is know for having driver issues but Power-PC has a fairly standard set of hardware and most drivers are available.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has PowerPC builds, it might be worth trying:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: I tried Ubuntu: Unity and Gnome3 don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest builds of [Lubuntu 15.10](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/) or [Ubuntu MATE 15.10](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/) on PowerPC.

However, the best experience you will get with the original Mac OS X 10.5.8 (actually I am writing this on Mac OS X on my Powerbook G4).